# Fetch Case's Call logs via REST API

Tags: rest-api, servicecloud

I'm looking for a way to fetch all tasks which represent Call Logs for a given Case via REST API. The tasks are created via 'Log a Call' UI and seem to have no specific distinction from any other kind of tasks ([more info](http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000176415&language=en_US)). Still, is there a way to do that?

Thanks!